# DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found error?

Tags: grails, geb, grails-4

i am using grails 4.0.10 and doing geb functional testing, so far it has been working great

today i got this message when running functional test

```
Execution failed for task ':configureChromeDriverBinary'.
> com.github.erdi.gradle.webdriver.repository.DriverUrlNotFoundException: Driver url not found for name: "chromedriver", version: "108.0.5359.71", platform: "windows", bit: "32"
```

i downloaded the latest chrome driver today from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=108.0.5359.71/

and in build.gradle i have put

```
webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver {
        version = '108.0.5359.71'
        architecture = 'X86'
    }
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}
```

why is it still saying driver url not found for that version?

i checked my chrome version and it is 108.0.5359.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)

the browser updated today to that version

is anyone else doing geb functional test and is anyone seeing this issue?

i appreciate any guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per WebDriver binaries Gradle plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/erdi/webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin#configuring-download-urls), by default the versions specified in `webdriverBinaries` configuration block are resolved to urls based on [WebDriver Extensions Maven Plugin's `package.json` file](https://github.com/webdriverextensions/webdriverextensions-maven-plugin-repository/blob/master/repository-3.0.json). It looks like the file is behind at the moment with the latest version for chromedriver being `106.0.5249.61`. I would suggest you create your own configuration file which lists an entry for `108.0.5359.71` and configure the plugin to use it [as described in the documentation](https://github.com/erdi/webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin#configuring-download-urls).

Comment: thanks i just put it as 106.0.5249.61 and it works.